# Spring OAuth2 - custom "OAuth Approval" page at oauth/authorize

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

what is recommended way to create custom pages OAuth Approval page:

[image: default page]

I have to completely override the stuff on the page, need to add styles, branding etc. What is the right way to achieve that? Where could I see the source of the default page to use it as a starting point?

I also need to override the /login page but I think the approach of overriding it is going to be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The recommended way is to provide a normal Spring MVC `@RequestMapping` for the "/oauth/confirm_access". You can look at `WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint` for the default implementation. Don't forget to use `@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")` in your controller.

Comment: Is there another way to customize the page. In my setup application `HandlerMapping` has order lower than `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping` and as a result, custom mappings are picked up after default ones and don't override the latter?

Comment: I don't think I follow that. You just have to provide a resource at /oauth/confirm_access (or whatever you customize the endpoint path to be). It doesn't matter how you do it.

Comment: `Framew‌​orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping` has an order of `Order.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 2`, but my custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` has an order of `Order.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` thus `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#getHandler` picks `Framew‌​orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping`'s mapping and request never reaches my customer controller. Unfortunately changing orders is not an option for me at this moment. What I ended up doing is `authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalPage("forward:/oauth/customer_path")`; in `@PostConstruct` method of `AuthorizationServerConfiguration`.

Comment: Since `/oauth/customer_path` is not mapped by `Framew‌​orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping`, dispatcher reaches my controller's mapping.

Comment: Also, don't forget to change your controller to have a bean name os something other than WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint otherwise the Spring one will get precedence (as I found out eventually).....

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @DaveSyer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29435900/925675), which should work for the most of the cases. Sometimes based on configuration and customization the aforementioned method may not work, if `Framew‌orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping` from Spring Security OAuth package has higher order than `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` of your application. If this is the case, then servlet dispatcher will never reach you mapping and will always show the default page.

One way to fix it is to change the order of mappers, given that `Framew‌orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping`'s order is `Order.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 2`.

Another way is to set the approval page to a custom URL, not mapped by `Framew‌orkEndpointHandlerMa‌pping`, thus servlet dispatcher will reaches you application's mapping

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalPage("forward:/oauth/custom_confirm_access");
        authorizationEndpoint.setErrorPage("forward:/oauth/custom_error");
    }
}
```

With such a configuration mappings of `/oauth/custom_confirm_access` and `/oauth/custom_error` will be used as a confirmation page and an error page respectively.