# How to add custom OAuth approval page to 'Spring Boot OAuth2 Identity Server'

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, identityserver2

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = AuthorizationRequest.class)
public class WhiteLableController {

    @RequestMapping("/oauth/confirm_access")
    public String getAccessConfirmation() throws Exception {
        return "access_confirmation";
    }
}
```

when I keep the access_confirmation.html in 'public' or 'static' folders in spring boot its not working. Could someone help me on this ?

404 Error Page :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 18 14:11:19 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring OAuth2 - custom "OAuth Approval" page at oauth/authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345508/spring-oauth2-custom-oauth-approval-page-at-oauth-authorize)

Comment: the solution doesn't works in newer spring version.