# Custom login and approval ui page in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using a default login and approval page in Spring Security OAuth2, but I want to use a custom page. I found an example for a custom login page, but I couldn't find example for both a login and approval page.

Below is my default login page and approval page for authentication.

[image: Login]
[image: OAuth Approval]

Comment: Did you looked at the following Stack Overflow answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345508/spring-oauth2-custom-oauth-approval-page-at-oauth-authorize

Comment: Yes but i was getting error but i found solution on this page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345508/spring-oauth2-custom-oauth-approval-page-at-oauth-authorize). Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to share your solution.